# How to get the total length of all dictionary values (strings)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, string-length

Say I have a dictionary that contains a bunch of strings:

`d = {'seq1':'AGG', 'seq2':'GCCG', 'seq3':'', 'seq4':'TTAAA'}`

What is the best way to get the **sum of all the lengths** of the values?
In this example, the total length is 3 + 4 + 0 + 5, so I want the output to be 12.

Is it possible to do this without using loops?

Comment: Why sometimes people want to do something without the classic tools ? Please tell me, i'd like to know :)

Comment: @azro what do you mean by "the classic tools"?

Comment: Just the classic operators, like `for`

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using loops? That depends on what you mean by 'loop'. You can't do this without *iteration*, but you don't have to use a *for* loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the sum of a comprehension:

```
sum((len(v) for v in d.values()))
```

Comment: Technically this is a generator expression rather than a comprehensive, although that's even better for this situation. You can omit one set of the parentheses when passing a generator expression as the only argument, as you are here.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `sum` with `map`

**Ex:**

```
d = {'seq1':'AGG', 'seq2':'GCCG', 'seq3':'', 'seq4':'TTAAA'}
print(sum(map(len, d.values())))    # -->12
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over dictionary and get length value of each value in the dictionary

```
totalStringLength = 0
for item in d.values():
    totalStringLength += len(item)
```